# Coding in Google Earth Engine for common ratio and band combinations used in mineral exploration

Tags: google-earth-engine, band, geology, aster, band-ratio

There are common ratio and band combinations throughout the geological literature, for example: [ASTER Mineral Index Processing
Manual](https://www.ga.gov.au/webtemp/image_cache/GA7833.pdf)

I am trying to use Google Earth Engine to replicate some of these combinations. The most recent error that I have is that "'phengite' is not a band"... I thought by renaming the bands I could get around this for mapping a layer...

Here is my code:

```
var ASTER_collection = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2019-11-01' , '2020-05-01');
var image = ASTER_collection.median();

print(ASTER_collection);

// Expression using image band names.
var bandNameExp_1 = '(b("B05")) / (b("B06"))';
var bandNameImg_1 = image.expression(bandNameExp_1).rename('phengite');

var bandNameExp_2 = '(b("B07")) / (b("B06"))';
var bandNameImg_2 = image.expression(bandNameExp_2).rename('muscovite');

var bandNameExp_3 = '(b("B07")) / (b("B05"))';
var bandNameImg_3 = image.expression(bandNameExp_3).rename('kaolinite');

// Ternary with Variables
var ASTER_AlOH = ('phengite' , 'muscovite' , 'kaolinite');
var ASTER_mosaic = image.select(ASTER_AlOH).clip(geometry);
var ASTER_display = {bands: ASTER_AlOH, min: 0, max: 255};

Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(ASTER_mosaic, ASTER_display, 'ASTER_AlOH');
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.

1. The one actually causing the error report is: You've made some computed bands, but they are stored in the variables `bandNameImg_1` through `bandNameImg_3`, *not* the variable `image`, so when you write `image.select(ASTER_AlOH)` it fails.
2. Also, the line with `ASTER_AlOH` is not correct: the parentheses must be square brackets to make a list. Due to how JavaScript syntax works, this would have only taken the 'phengite' band.

   ```js
   var ASTER_AlOH = ['phengite', 'muscovite' , 'kaolinite'];
   ```
3. You're computing a *ratio* of two values in the 1-255 range. This ratio is therefore likely to be in a range more like 0-2, so the `ASTER_display` visualization parameters need to be adjusted.
4. It is harmless but entirely unnecessary to `select()` *and* specify bands in visualization parameters.
5. Finally, you have a data-source problem: the bands you're trying to use (B05-B07) are fully masked within the date range `('2019-11-01' , '2020-05-01')`. The data you're trying to visualize simply doesn't exist. I'm not familiar with ASTER so I can't tell you why this is the case or what would be best to use instead.

Putting fixes for all these together, here's a script that at least produces some data. I can't promise that this is what you wanted to obtain (in particular, the date range is no longer 2019-2020), but it is at least a working program that can be a basis for modification.

In addition to fixing the problems I've also removed some variable definitions that didn't seem especially valuable, in favor of placing them in-line in the larger expressions.

```js
var ASTER_collection = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003")
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2001-11-01', '2002-05-01');
var image = ASTER_collection.median();

print(ASTER_collection);

var ratioImage = ee.Image.cat(  // combine all images' bands into bands
  image,
  image.expression('b("B05") / b("B06")').rename('phengite'),
  image.expression('b("B07") / b("B06")').rename('muscovite'),
  image.expression('b("B07") / b("B05")').rename('kaolinite')
);

var ASTER_AlOH = ['phengite', 'muscovite' , 'kaolinite'];

Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(
  ratioImage.clip(geometry),
  {bands: ASTER_AlOH, min: 0, max: 2},
  'ASTER_AlOH'
);
```

[image: Screenshot of results]